# robot framework replace function for multiple words

Tags: python, robotframework

I have variables defined in my varaibles.py file

```
AUTHENTICATE_TEXT_LANG = u"Authentifizieren Sie sich als <user-name>,um Ihr Konto mit <oidc-text> zu verknüpfen."
```

I want replace the AUTHENTICATE_TEXT_LANG  above two    and .

```
${AUTHENTICATE_TEXT_LANG}=  Replace String    ${AUTHENTICATE_TEXT_LANG}  <user-name> <oidc-text> ${username} TEXT
```

I know String replace doesn't have like this functionality, is there any alternative approach to replace multiple words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the `Replace String` two times:

```
${AUTHENTICATE_TEXT_LANG}=    Replace String    ${AUTHENTICATE_TEXT_LANG}    <user-name>    ${username}
${AUTHENTICATE_TEXT_LANG}=    Replace String    ${AUTHENTICATE_TEXT_LANG}    <oidc-text>    TEXT
```

You can also create your own keyword, e.g. in Python and import it as a library. But that sounds like too much work where you can easily use two lines. It might be worth doing if you have to substitute say three and more words in one string, then I'd probably go for a custom keyword.